# Can a user award half their bounty after being AWOL?

Tags: support, bounty

Scenario:

A user fixes a sizeable bounty on a question then real life intervenes and that user is absent for a week or more. At the end of the bounty period the system kicks into action and awards half the bounty to the answer that  has gained the highest number of upvotes during the user's absence.

All fine and dandy. But what happens when the user returns? Can the questioner award the second half of their bounty? Are there mitigating circumstances?

Yes, I am that user. And no, I do not possess a smart phone, and I had other things more urgent on my mind than awarding bounties.

EDIT
I suspect that the answer will be negative, but I'd like an explanation. I believe exceptions should be made especially if users have proven to be reliable, and, reasonable people.

EDIT 2
**ANSWER**

No answers after three days. Luckily, I posted the same question on Meta Stack Exchange  and received two answers almost immediately. It appears there is nothing that I nor any moderator can do. There appears to be no mitigating circumstances, which would allow me or the system to reward the remaining 100 points. The only alternative solution is to reset the bounty but that would mean doubling the bounty.

I am not allowed to offer less or the same amount as before. It's a pity, because after offering sixteen bounties (not only on my questions) and never having missed a deadline, a user is "penalised" and loses out on his 200/100 points. The only thing I can add is  "at least I tried".

Comment: I don't think so. That's just how the system works.

Comment: Welcome back. Hope everything is all right. :)

Comment: @choster thanks, that's very kind of you.

Comment: *knock*, *knock* Hello, is anyone home?